# Selenium IDE: How to Upload Excel sheet available at Google drive shared location

Tags: selenium, ide

I'm stuck at one point as per one of my current going project. I need to access & upload an Excel sheet and it is available at Google drive which is shared for public. I tried to access it by its shared link but it didn't work for me. How can I do this?

Google drive share location path

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sIXqIznm8vMUdsT09WUXhlY3c/view?usp=sharing

file name: St_buyer.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file as shown below
[image]

Comment: Hi Its not working i tried these scenario...   `<tr>
<td>type</td><td>css=#fileName</td>td>**share file location **</td></tr>
`

Comment: First i have to click on browser button and in value i have to set the share location path...  i want to pass whole xlsx file . my systems will automatically read the value inside that excel sheet.